# How to hide specific keys from virtual keyboard for Maui Blazor?

Tags: css, blazor, maui

I am using an input field for Maui Blazor mobile app. The input is binded to an int property but I would like to hide all non numeric input keys as the picture shows below.

[image]

Comment: May I know on which platform do you want to hide all non numeric input keys?

Comment: It's a Maui Blazor phone application targeting Android and IPhone

Comment: For system default virtual keyboard, I don't think it's possible to hide it. You may need use the same techniques you use in [Xamarin](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard-with-xamarin-forms-android-4fa3b83dad1d) to do so as in Maui. It's because that the customization is not Maui Blazor specific behavior but comes from the underlying Android or iOS API.